# What is the difference between "/" and "//" directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

I just discovered that I can access to admin directory through two path :

`cd /` 
`cd //`

And in the second case (`cd //`), when I do `pwd`, output is : `//` 
And the same when I'm going into /boot/ (pwd : `//boot`), /home/ (pwd : `//home`) and every other admin directory.

So what is the difference ? Is it just an alias, a bug or a specific feature ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919 they're treated as a single / .

Comment: `/` is NOT any kind of admin directory. And as for `//`, simply try `cd //` then `pwd` and you'll see that no, `//` is not a different path, it just works the same, that's all.

Comment: @Geoffroy isn't that exactly their question. If you do `cd //` then `pwd` you get `//` back instead of `/`

Comment: @matt I'm getting `/`, so I guess it depends on the shell maybe?

Comment: @Geoffroy I'm getting `//` same for `cd //home/user/` the pwd returns `//home/user` although `//home//user` gets rid of the extra / between home and user. One thing that doesn't fail though is `realpath //home/user` gets ride of the superflous slashes.

Comment: I can confirm that `cd //` results in the current directory shown as `//` while `cd ///` (or more slashes) results in `/`. Tested with Bash on Ubuntu 20.04 and on Windows in a Git Bash.

Comment: @Bodo It's exactly the same for me ! (Fedora 35)

Comment: cd sets the environment variable PWD to whatever you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `realpath` to get the real path of your current directory.
`//` is a symlink of `/` in some linux distributions and `cd` set `pwd` by what you've entered.
It will be the same for all symlink directories you are in, if you get `pwd` after `cd` !